# Can I read/write the name of the Illustrator artboard in Applescript

Tags: applescript, adobe-illustrator

Is it possible to get the name of an Illustrator artboard in Applescript?

This script works perfectly until I try to get the name of the artboard:

```
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
  tell document 1
       set artboards_count to count of artboards
       set c to 1       
       repeat while c <= artboards_count 
          log index of artboard c as text
          log artboard rectangle of artboard c as text 
          log name of artboard c as text -- this line fails
          set c to c + 1
       end repeat
   end tell
end tell
```

the line `log name of artboard c as text` fails - everything else works ok.

The message is:

```
Adobe Illustrator got an error: Can’t get name of artboard 1 of document 1. (-1728)
```

Any idea as to why?

Setting the name fails too, BTW. However if I do

```
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
  tell document 1
       return properties of artboard 1
  end tell
end tell
```

I get (carriage returns added for clarify):

```
artboard rectangle:0.0, 0.0, 841.889999999999, -595.280000000001, 
   ruler PAR:1.0, show center:false, show cross hairs:false, 
   show safe areas:false, ruler origin:0.0, 0.0, name:Artboard 1,
   container:document 1, best type:reference, default type:reference,
   class:artboard, index:1
```

from which one would think the property `name`should be there.

Comment: Have you looked in Adobe Illustrator AppleScript Dictionary to see what properties the object has?

Comment: @user3439894 - both in the dictionary and here: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/illustrator/pdf/Illustrator_Scripting_Reference_AppleScript_cc.pdf page 14

Comment: I don't have Adobe Illustrator, so I cannot test, however what happens if you query `document 1` to `return properties of artboard 1`, does it return a _list_ of its _properties_ and the _value_ for each and is _name_ present with a _value_ in the _list_ returned?

Comment: @user3439894 - I edited the question: yes, _name_ is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name property is read-only so there is no way to change it once the artboard exists. And even though you can get the properties of an artboard, you can’t convert it to a string if you simply want to target a particular artboard. But there is a way to do it nonetheless that I discovered by accident. Suppose you have several artboards and want to target the artboard named "Squash this". Here's how to do that:

```
Tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    tell current document
        set artCount to number of artboards
        repeat with i from 1 to artCount
            set artProp to get properties of artboard i
            try
                set propString to artProp as string --this will fail
            on error
                set errorDisp to text of result --this captures the text of the error
            set errorDispText to errorDisp as string --changes the text to a ¬ 
                searchable string
            end try
            if errorDispText contains "quash" then
                display notification "errorDispText" --oddly enough, this displays just ¬
                  the artboard name 
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
     end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution could be coercion; take the record returned from the Artboard properties and coerce the record into a list. So, your name property from the record becomes the 7th item in the list. The code below will get Artboard dimensions, name and index, and place them into a list for later use in your script.

Hope this helps!

```
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    set artboardDetails to {}
    tell front document
        set allArtboards to every artboard
        repeat with i from 1 to count of allArtboards
            set thisArtboard to item i of allArtboards
            set thisArtboardProps to properties of thisArtboard
            set thisArtboardDimensions to artboard rectangle of thisArtboardProps
            set thisArtboardIndex to index of thisArtboardProps

            --WORKAROUND
            set thisArtboardPropsCoerce to thisArtboardProps as list
            set thisArtboardName to item 7 of thisArtboardPropsCoerce

            set the end of artboardDetails to {thisArtboardName, thisArtboardIndex, thisArtboardDimensions}
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell

(*
--WORKAROUND
The following is a workaround for error returned from:
set anArtboardName to the name of anArtboard -- this line will not return a result, just errors out

BUT WE NEED TO WATCH OUT FOR THE COERCED LIST!
So, we have to coerce the properties record of artboard to a list first

WEIRD I KNOW!
The coercion then changes the record of 11 items to a list of 12 items
set anArtboardProps to properties of anArtboard as list
set anArtboardName to item 7 of anArtboardProps

NOW LETS MATCH UP THE COERCION ITEMS
The first lines are from the record properties, and the second lines are from the coerced to list versions.

01. artboard rectangle:{0.0, 768.0, 1366.0, 0.0}, 
01. {0.0, 768.0, 1366.0, 0.0}, 

02. ruler PAR:1.0, 
02. 1.0, 

03. show center:false, 
03. false, 

04. show cross hairs:false, 
04. false, 

05. show safe areas:false, 
05. false, 

06. ruler origin:{0.0, 0.0}, 
06. {0.0, 0.0}, 

07. name:"Artboard 1", 
07. "Artboard 1", 

08. container:document 1, 
08. document 1, 

09. best type:reference, 
09. reference, 

10. default type:reference, 
10. reference, 

11. index:1
11. artboard, 

12. NULL - nothing in the record
12. 1 - so this line is the index of the artboard
*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my workaround. As the «class bAl9» vanishes every time you compile, you have to copy/paste every time, but it works. And yes, «class bAl9» will turn to "name" and will not compile correctly the next time. Thanks Adobe !

```
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    tell document 1
        repeat with x in (every artboard)
            log index of x as text
            log artboard rectangle of x as text
            log «class bAl9» of x as text -- artboard's name property = «class bAl9»
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

The **name** property of artboards is **read/write**, it's easy to rename artboards this way once you get the trick.

Edit : For the loop in a list, I always use the **repeat with x in l** statement. It's smart and fast.

Answer (score 0):

Stu's answer was the best that I found. Coercing the record to a list is brilliant – I didn't even know you could do that. My code was:

```
    repeat with i from 1 to the (count of AllArtBoards)
        set ThisArtBoard to item i of AllArtBoards
        set ThisArtBoardName to item 7 of ((properties of ThisArtBoard) as list)
        set the end of AllArtBoardNames to ThisArtBoardName
    end repeat
```